# Преобразование даты, полученную из foaf.php в желаемый вид и получение количество лет/месяцев/дней

Tags: php, вконтакте, дата

Я получаю следующую строку: **2016-03-02T09:03:26+03:00**

Как её можно преобразовать в желаемый вид, например: **01.01.2011 в 11:00**

Также хотел бы узнать, как можно сравнить две даты (текущую с полученной) и вывести указанный промежуток, например **прошло времени: 8 лет 10 месяцев 11 дней**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос 1:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d \в H:i';
$date = '2016-03-02T09:03:26+03:00';
$date = (new DateTime($date))->getTimestamp();
$return =  (new DateTime())
            ->setTimestamp($date)
            ->format($format);
echo $return; // 2016-03-01 в 22:03
```

Вопрос 2:

```
$interval = date_diff((new DateTime($date)), (new DateTime(date('c'))));
print_r($interval); 
/* DateInterval Object(
       [y] => 3
       [m] => 4
       [d] => 27
       [h] => 5
       [i] => 30
       [s] => 24
       [f] => 0
       [weekday] => 0
       [weekday_behavior] => 0
       [first_last_day_of] => 0
       [invert] => 0
       [days] => 1244
       [special_type] => 0
       [special_amount] => 0
       [have_weekday_relative] => 0
       [have_special_relative] => 0
  )*/
```

[пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/a2254d72edd428686a29490034b3ddd85d158df9)

Comment: Большое вам спасибо, вы очень помогли